# Stop javascript function which is executing all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have multiple JavaScript functions and all of them run at the same time and are running in a loop because I'm reading some data from REST API.

Is there any way to stop execution of those scripts with a button or something?

```js
function termostat1_on_off_get() {
  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.1.113:8080/rest/items/termostat1_on_off/state"
  });

  request.done(function(data) { 
    console.log("On/off" + data);
    if (data == 1) {
      termostat1_on_off = "Vklopljen";
      $("#m_t1_vklopljen").css('background-color', '#cccccc');
      $("#m_t1_izklopljen").css('background-color', '#efefef');
    } else {
      termostat1_on_off = "Izklopljen";
      $("#m_t1_vklopljen").css('background-color', '#efefef');
      $("#m_t1_izklopljen").css('background-color', '#cccccc');
    }
  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { 
    console.log( "Failure: " + textStatus );
  });

  setTimeout(termostat1_on_off_get, 5000);
}

termostat1_on_off_get();
```

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` recursively, use `setInterval` instead, then you can just stop it.

Comment: Your funciton is having recursive code pattern. It calls itself after every 5 seconds. Can you tell when you want to stop its execution ?

Comment: @George: It's just as easy (sometimes easier) to stop when using `setTimeout` pseudo-recursively as when using `setInterval`.

Comment: @George chained `setTimeout()` is better practice as it stops events building up. Eg. if you call the request every 1s, yet the request itself takes 2s to complete you're just going to choke up the user's connection to the server.

Comment: I would suggest you to use WebSockets or HTTP Long Polling request and only on some changes on the server to send data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearTimeout()` to stop an in-progress timeout from running. To do this you need to save the id returned from the `setTimeout` call, then provide it as a parameter to `clearTimeout()`, like this:

```js
var timeout;

function termostat1_on_off_get()
{
    // your ajax logic here...

    // inside the callbacks:
    timeout = setTimeout(termostat1_on_off_get, 5000);
}

termostat1_on_off_get();

function stopTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

***However***, you should note that AJAX polling is an anti-pattern which should really be avoided. If you need to keep the UI in sync with the server then you should look in to WebSockets or Server Side Events instead. They perform much better, and save your server from having a meltdown.

Answer (score -1):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```js
var i = 0;

function log() {
  console.log(i++);
}

var interval = setInterval(log, 1000);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval)
};
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Chained `setTimeout()` is better practice as it stops events building up. Eg. if you call the request every 1s, yet the request itself takes 2s to complete you're just going to choke up the user's connection to the server. Although AJAX polling isn't exactly good practice in the first place, but nevermind :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I get what you're saying, the problem is, with OPs code, it will do that anyway as the `setTimeout()` isn't in the callback function on the AJAX request, but as you've mentioned _AJAX polling is an anti-pattern_ so they shouldn't really go with either option